# Amazon Data Lifecycle Manager: "no attached EBS-backed volumes" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have created a Amazon Data Lifecycle Manager policy but after a day it is showing this error:

> There are no attached EBS-backed volumes on the instance id

However, if I create a snapshot on my own without the Data Lifecycle Manager, I was able to create a snapshot.

The instance id is correct though. Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you able to document some steps so that we can try to reproduce this problem ourselves? For example, does it happen if you create a new instance and try a backup policy on it? If so, please edit your question with these details.